# PhpStorm or SublimeText: Search form class name (CSS) for specific tag

Tags: html, search, phpstorm, sublimetext3

How do I search form a specific class or id for specific tag?

example:

```
<h3 class="heading">Heading 3 </h3>
<h3 class="heading bold"> Heading 3 </h3>
<h3 class="heading"> Heading 3 </h3>
<h3 class="heading"> Heading 3 </h3>
<h3 class="heading bold underline"> Heading 3 </h3>
<h3 class="heading lite"> Heading 3 </h3>
<h3 class="heading"> Heading 3 </h3>
```

How do I search for H3's with class bold, right now I can either search for all tags with 'bold' class or I all H3 tags.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using regex search.
In PhpStorm I just used the following regex search term:

```
\<h3.*?bold
```

This will find every line, that starts with "h3" then "any characters" until the word "bold" is found.

You can do a regex search term on linux/windows using "Ctrl + F" in the document you want to search (or "Ctrl + Tab + F" to search in all files of your project)

And then when you get the search bar above your file content, just tick the "Regex" Checkbox and enter the search query above.

When you get the results you want, you can also click the "Select all occurences" checkbox, to make them all selected.